# Simple explanation of List.Fold and List.Foldback in F#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data, f#-3.0

Can anyone please explain in a very simple way what is List.Fold and List.Foldback in F#. I have read some few books and tried to search online for a simple explanation I still don't understand it.

-This is not a duplicate question and it has not been answered in the other link.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the same question, that one is focused on when `foldBack` is needed over `fold`, while this one is about understanding `fold`.

Comment: `List.fold (+) 0 [1; 2; 3]` is `((0 + 1) + 2) + 3`. And `List.foldBack (+) [1; 2; 3] 0` is `1 + (2 + (3 + 0))` 

Answer (score 12):

The best way to understand it is with an example. Imagine you have list of numbers and you want to find out the total. In imperative programming you could do this:

```
let numbers = [ 19 ; 52 ; 35 ; 27]

let mutable total = 0
for n in numbers do
    total <- total + n

printfn "%A" total   // 133
```

it is a good solution but not functional. Lets use `List.fold` to do the same:

```
numbers
|> List.fold (fun total n -> total + n) 0
|> printfn "%A"    // 133
```

voila! If you squint you can recognize the same elements in both solutions.

- Your state: `total`
- Your folder operation that takes the prior state and an element of the list and returns a new state: `total + n`
- Your initial value: `0`

Lets look at the signature of `List.fold`:

```
val List.fold: 
   folder: 'State -> 'T -> 'State ->
   state : 'State  ->
   list  : 'T list 
        -> 'State
```

See how the elements match up?

`List.foldBack` is the same but the elements are fed in reverse order. The order of the parameters is also different.

---

One of the interesting things about `fold` is that in many cases it can replace a tail recursive function:

If you didn't have `List.fold` and wanted to implement a `totalF` function without mutable, how would you do it? You would need recursion, better yet tail recursion:

```
let rec totalF total ns =
    match ns with
    | []        ->         total
    | n :: tail -> totalF (total + n) tail

numbers
|> totalF 0
|> printfn "%A"    // 133
```

Again you can see all the elements as before. In fact if we make `total + n` into a parameter of `totalF`:

```
let rec totalF f total ns =
    match ns with
    | []        -> total
    | n :: tail -> totalF f (f total n) tail

numbers
|> totalF (fun total n -> total + n) 0
|> printfn "%A"    // 133
```

You get `fold`, the signature and use are the same:

```
val totalF: 
   f    : 'a -> 'b -> 'a ->
   total: 'a             ->
   ns   : 'b list        
       -> 'a
```

Comment: Thanks, AMieres your answer was really helpful.